# How to use middleware that requires socket connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am using `express.io` and am trying to craft a middleware that requires a connection to a remote server via two sockets. However, I am having a problem.

```
var net = require('net');

module.exports = function (host, port) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    req._messages = net.connect(port, host);
    req._commands = net.connect(port, host);

    req._messages.on('data', function (data) {
      req.io.broadcast('data', data.toString('ascii'));
    });

    req._messages.write('CF I\r');  // initialization command
    next();
  }
}
```

then in my main app:

```
var port = process.env.CYLON_PORT;
var host = process.env.CYLON_HOST;
var app = require('express.io').http().io();
app.use(require('./cylon/controller')(host, port));
module.exports = app;
```

However, I am coming across a problem. On each request, it attempts to reconnect. This causes an `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`. Ideally, I would like this to connect once when the application starts and maintain that socket, but it needs to intercept each connect.

How can I use sockets in middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that way:

```
var net = require('net');

module.exports = function (host, port) {
  var messagesConnection = net.connect(port, host);
  var commandsConnection = net.connect(port, host);

  return function (req, res, next) {
    req._messages = messagesConnection;
    req._commands = commandsConnection;

    req._messages.on('data', function (data) {
      req.io.broadcast('data', data.toString('ascii'));
    });

    req._messages.write('CF I\r');  // initialization command
    next();
  }
}
```

The call to `require('./cylon/controller')(host, port)` will start the connections and they will then be reused each time the middleware is called.

**Edit**: I'm wondering whether you really need to set all those new fields on you `req` object. You could have some files that export `io`, `messagesConnection` and `commandsConnection` for instance, and you could require them when needed.

Here you end up adding an even listener on `messagesConnection` each time the middleware is called, which is everything but good.

**Edit2**: What you could do instead, because you seem to be using `express-io`:

```
var net = require('net');

module.exports = function (io, host, port) {
  var messagesConnection = net.connect(port, host);
  var commandsConnection = net.connect(port, host);

  messagesConnection.on('data', function (data) {
    io.broadcast('data', data.toString('ascii'));
  });

  messagesConnection.write('CF I\r');  // initialization command

  return function (req, res, next) {
    req._messages = messagesConnection;
    req._commands = commandsConnection;
    next();
  }
}
```

And in your main file:

```
var port = process.env.CYLON_PORT;
var host = process.env.CYLON_HOST;
var app = require('express.io').http().io();
app.use(require('./cylon/controller')(app.io, host, port));
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still lead to a memory leak? The `req._messages.on` would still be used every time

Comment: Yes it will (cf. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_event_listener ). Moreover it will also trigger the callback for each event listener, leading to events being broadcasted multiple times. That's definitely not what you want.

Comment: @corvid: I edited my answer to add a possible solution.